# How can I download a csv file from a button in rvest [R]?

Tags: css, r, csv, download, rvest

I am new to rvest and I need to write a script that downloads a csv file from a website. The website is http://phoible.org/inventories.

At the right hand side, there is drop-down button that gives the option to download the data in several formats (including the csv file I am interested in). First, I inspected the css content and I found out that the button I am interested in has the following css:

```
<a href="#" id="dt-dl-csv" onclick="document.location.href = CLLD.DataTable.current_url(&quot;Inventories&quot;, &quot;csv&quot;); return false;">csv</a>
```

Then I tried the following code:

```
p = html_session("http://www.phoible.org/inventories")
csv_link = p %>% 
html_nodes("a") %>% 
html_attr("onclick")
```

However, I get the following line:

```
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

I need to automatically download the csv file to my computer. I would really appreciate any help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `data.table::fread("http://phoible.org/inventories.csv")` seems to work for me, so you could try that URL with `rvest`.

Comment: Hi @nrussell, thank you so much for your solution. It worked perfectly. Cheers.

Comment: Hi @nrussell, do you know why I am meeting this error?
Error in curl::curl_download(input, tmpFile, mode = "wb", quiet = !showProgress) : 
  Unrecognized content encoding type. libcurl understands deflate, gzip content encodings.

Comment: Using "http" instead of "https" seemed to work. Thanks